# Maven deploy plugin doesn't see my repository inside distributionManagement in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-deploy-plugin

I tried to deploy into my remote repository (Nexus) with the command `mvn deploy` on command line. By doing this I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project pro-tools-maven-plugin: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

I specified my repositories inside `distributionManagement` in the `pom.xml`. Username and password are stored in `settings.xml`.

**Snippet of `pom.xml`:**

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>thirdparty</id>
        <name>3rd Party (Releases)</name>
        <url>http://bla.net:11000/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>thirdparty_snapshots</id>
        <name>3rd Party (Snapshots)</name>
        <url>http://bla.net:11000/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty_snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please show the full pom file, cause the error message is a contradiction to what you have written.

Comment: Ok, due to a pretty large pom.xml I only show you a snippet of the pom file. I hope that will be enough!

Comment: I also checked the view of maven on the pom file with mvn help:effective-pom which showed me that the destributionManagement is included. All further informations for the repositories are stored in settings.xml.

Comment: Does it work if you change the IDs for the repositories to "releases" and "snapshots"?

Comment: I thought the only important by usage of the ID's is that the repository ID's inside the pom file have to be the same as the server ID's in the settings.xml?!?

Comment: Its hards to guess what's wrong, cause there could be some comment markers in the pom file, cause error message says something different. May be you can put the full pom on pastebin like?

Comment: Problem solved!!! Stupid failure! There was a submodule which does not inherit from the parent pom. So it has no distributionManagement tag.